# How to solve this question? Let $0, a, b, c$ be the vertices of a square in counterclockwise order.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $0, a, b, c$ be the vertices of a square in counterclockwise order. Then find $\frac{b}{a}$ and $\frac{c}{a}$.

I got $1-i$ and $-i$, but my teacher said that it was wrong.
Since it is counterclockwise, I got that $=−$, $=−+$,$=$. Then, $\frac{b}{a}=\frac{−+}{−}=1−$. $\frac{c}{a}=\frac{}{−}=−$.

Comment: Ideas on how to make this clearer:
Put a question, not (only) the assumption in the title.; what do you mean by "enter"?; what is "rectangular form"? What does "/" mean for points? Apparently you identify points with complex numbers, can you explain that?

Comment: It looks like you're taking your vertices in clockwise order. Also is there any reason to believe that the square has horizontal and vertical sides?

Comment: It is $1+i$, not $1-i$...

Comment: @paw88789 Why do you mention horizontal and vertical sides ?

Comment: I took $x$ to be real (since a complex number is often represented as $x+iy$. I see that may have been an incorrect assumption on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are representing the square in the argand plane.

Thus, taking the origin as $0$ and drawing the square in the first quadrant, we get $a = x$, $b = x + xi$ and $c = xi$.

Hence, $\frac{b}{a} = \frac{x(1 + i)}{x} = 1 + i$ and $\frac{c}{a} = \frac{xi}{x} = i$.

Additional remark: I am making the assumption that the square has horizontal and vertical sides. If this is not the case, we will not necessarily get the answer above.

Comment: *"I am making the assumption that the square has horizontal and vertical sides. If this is not the case, we will not necessarily get the answer above."* ... I believe the ultimate purpose of this exercise is to demonstrate that we *will* necessarily get the answer above, *always* (unless $a=b=c=0$). After all, point (and complex number) $c$ is the counter-clockwise rotation of $a$ (*wherever that is*) by $90^\circ$ about $0$; such a rotation is accomplished via multiplication by $i$, so $c=ai$, whence $c/a=i$. Slightly-more-complicated reasoning applies to $b$.